# Is it possible to use an accelerator/collider as a space engine?

Tags: estimation, rocket-science, propulsion, particle-accelerators

I was just trying to get a discussion going about physics that we can already create. I did not realize that I would have to write a paper to ask a simple question. Is it possible to use an accelerator/collider as a space engine?

Comment: Please briefly define what you mean by "accelerator/collider", and explain briefly what physics principles you feel would allow it to produce "thrust".

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is asking if a particle accelerator can be used as a thruster.  The answer is "yes", in principle. Even ignoring their enormous mass, today's big particle accelerators are extremely inefficient, putting a miniscule fraction of expended energy into the particle beam.

An ion thruster is a particle accelerator of sorts, and is better than a chemical rocket engine for some applications, primarily because its exhaust velocity is much higher than that of a chemical rocket.  As a result, an ion thruster uses much less reaction mass.  As long as there is an external source of power such as photovoltaic panels, an ion thruster is superior for applications that do not require high acceleration.

Note that the emitted particle beam must be neutralized: for every proton in the beam, an electron must also be in the beam -- otherwise charge builds up on the spacecraft.

It turns out that *if* there were a very low-mass relativistic particle accelerator that could be put on a spacecraft, and a low-mass, extremely efficient photovoltaic membrane, it would be a better use of the power received by a laser driven sail -- better than just reflecting the light.  This idea has received very little attention, probably because of the difficulty of imagining how to make a sufficiently low-mass accelerator and photovoltaic membrane.